# distribution of prime powers

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $f(x)$ be the number of prime powers less than $x$
(by prime power I mean any number of the form $p^n$ such that $p$ is prime and $n \ge 1$.)

Consider the limit: lim x->∞ f(x)/x
I would like to know the value of L
In particular, this article seems to suggest that the limit tend neither towards 0 nor 1 however I do not have the knowledge needed to understand the it:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160270602/abstract

Thanks

Comment: Are you counting the $n = 1$ terms, i.e. the primes themselves, or just their higher powers?

Comment: Isn't $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)$?

Comment: I don't know, if you can prove that or give me a link to a proof I'll accept that as an answer

Comment: Use *\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}* to better express $L$ in symbols. This generates thus: $$L = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$ You can also use *\cfrac* and *\dfrac* to change the size of the fraction.

Comment: I tried it and the result aren't good, I'm probably making a simple mistake, feel free to point it out

Comment: That is probably theworst URL in existence.

Comment: sorry about that, if you know how to hide the url in the link let me know and I'll change it or change it your self if you can

Comment: [Here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160270602/abstract) is a better link to the article referenced above.

Comment: This article is not about what you think. It's investigating the distribution of *the fractional part* of $p^\gamma$ for primes $p$ and some $0<\gamma<1$, and those fractional parts are uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, not surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor$. Then
\begin{align}f(x)-\pi(x)=\sum_{\substack{p^m\le x \\ m\ge 2}}1=&\sum_{p^2\le x}1+\sum_{p^3\le x}1+\cdots +\sum_{p^N\le x}1\\[1mm]
=&\sum_{p\le x^{1/2}}1+\sum_{p\le x^{1/3}}1+\cdots +\sum_{p \le x^{1/N}}1\\[1mm]
=&\;\pi(x^{1/2})+\pi(x^{1/3})+\cdots +\pi(x^{1/N})\\[1mm]
\le&\;(N-1)\pi(x^{1/2})\\[1mm]
=&\;O\Big(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x}\log_2(x)\Big)=O(\sqrt{x})
\end{align}
Thus,
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{\pi(x)}{x}+O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})=O(\frac{1}{\log x})=o(1)$$
by the prime number theorem. As such, we have $L=0$.

Answer (score -2):

Let's define $\Pi_n(x)$ as the number of prime powers $p^n$ with exponent $n$ that are less than $x$. Clearly $\Pi_1(x) = \Pi(x)$, the usual prime counting function.

Since $p^n < x$ implies that $p < x^{1/n}$, we have
$$
\Pi_n(x) = \Pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)\, .
$$
Your $f(x)$ is:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pi_n(x)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)\, .
\end{align}
For fixed $x$, $x^{1/n}$ will eventually go to 1 as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so this sum will actually terminate at some point. (Actually the sum need only go up to the point where $x^{1/n} < 2$, i.e. $n_{max} = \left\lfloor \ln x / \ln 2 \right \rfloor$.)

Beyond that, at present, all I have are numerics (done in Mathematica) which loosely suggest that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0\, ,
$$
although convergence seems to be very, very slow. (Perhaps going as $1/\ln(x)$?)

Edit:

Numerically, it looks like the limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x/\ln(x)}
$$
may exist, and have a value $\ge 1$. (I suspect the actual limit is 1 itself, but the convergence is very slow.)

Edit 2:

For those down-voting this, note that the original questioner asked me (in the comments above) to post the proof of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)$. I'm just trying to be helpful. (Unless I've made an error here, in which case let me know.)

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem implies that $f(x)/x=O(1/\log x).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That may be so, but it's not instantly obvious to me. What about the additional terms in $f(x)$ with $n > 1$?